# increasing the performance of OS windows C++ portscanner

Tags: c++, performance, winsock, port-scanning

I wrote a port scanner in C++ that will work in windows using winsock, everything works the way i wanted it to its just that its very very slow it takes like 10 mins to scan three ports i was just wondering if there was a way to increase its performance!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WSOCK32.LIB")

int main()
{
    WSADATA data;
    SOCKET sock;
    int err, i, startport, endport;
    char ip[20];
    struct sockaddr_in sock_addr;
    FILE*fp1;

    printf("ip: ");
    scanf("\n%s", ip);
    printf("start port: ");
    scanf("%d", &startport);
    printf("end port: ");
    scanf("%d", &endport);

    if ((WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &data) != 0))
    {
        printf("Error: Winsock did not init!!!\n\n");
    }
    else
    {

    for (i = startport; i < endport; i++)
    {
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        sock_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
        sock_addr.sin_port = htons(i);
        sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        printf("Checking port %d\n", i);
        err = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        if (err == 0)
        {
            printf("Port Open!!!\n\n\a");
            fp1 = fopen("ports.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(fp1, "Port is open: %d\n\n", i);
            closesocket(sock);
            fclose(fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Port Closed!!!\n\n");
        }
    }
    WSACleanup();
    system("ports.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on CodeReview.SE

Comment: Some things to look at: Step 1) Look at your algorithms - see if anything can be improved. Step 2) Make sure you are compiling your code with optimizations enabled. Step 3) make sure the hardware you run on has adequate resources for what your program needs.

Comment: `#pragma comment(...` - That's really poor and non-portable way to link libraries. Use the facilities of your build system.

Comment: `FILE*fp1` - In a C++ program? No, please don't.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` - That header is deprecated in modern C++. Use `#include <cstdio>` if you must. Same for `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: `struct sockaddr_in sock_addr;` - In C++ the `struct` keyword is redundant there.

Comment: This looks like C compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` - Usually you want *more* warnings (to improve your code), *not* fewer.

Comment: `system("ports.txt")` - `system()` is a function you should avoid. Too many security problems. Besides, what are you even trying to do there? Is that text file executable??

Comment: I could go on, but I will just stop here.

Comment: Hit the code with a profiler and see what's soaking up the excess time. I'm not sure what version of Visual Studio you're using, but MSVC Pro 2015 has a pretty good profiler built in.

Comment: What is the timeout you have on connection attempts? The connections are executed serially (consider using threads) and Windows can spend quite a while waiting for a response from a connection attempt to a port that the receiver has been configured to silently drop.

Comment: How does the current Winsock documentation fail to help?

Comment: @user4581301 `connect()` does not support any kind of user-defined timeout (at least on Windows). Put the socket into non-blocking mode and then use `select()` with a timeout to wait for the `connect()` operation to finish.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a socket operates in **blocking** mode.  You are using a single loop to connect to each port in a serialized manner, waiting for one connect to finish before attempting the next connect.  So, of course performance will be slow.

For what you want to accomplish, you need to run multiple connect calls in parallel.  You have 3 choices for that:

- use **threads**.

For each blocking socket you create, start a worker thread to `connect()` it.  You can then create multiple sockets and run their threads at one time.  Use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) (or related function) to detect when each thread terminates when its `connect()` operation finishes.

This is OK for a small number of sockets, but it does not scale for large numbers.

- use **non-blocking sockets**.

For each socket you create, use [`ioctlsocket(FIONBIO)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-ioctlsocket) to put it into non-blocking mode.  You can then create multiple sockets and `connect()` them at one time.  Use [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select), [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsaasyncselect), or [`WSAEventSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect) to detect when each `connect()` operation finishes.

- use **overlapped socket I/O**.

Create each socket using [`WSASocket()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketw) with the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag enabled.  You can then create multiple sockets and [`ConnectEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_connectex) them at one time, specifying a separate `OVERLAPPED` struct for each one.  Use `WaitForMultipleObjects()`+[`GetOverlappedResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresult), or an [I/O Completion Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/i-o-completion-ports), to detect when each `ConnectEx()` operation finishes.